# Encontrar la posición en un array javascript

Tags: javascript

quisiera saber una forma de que cuando yo aprete un botón o un elemento darle una función para que me devuelva su posición en el array, porejemplo tengo 3 divs con un getElementsByClassName , y cuando clique sobre el tercero conseguir su posición en el array. Graciás.

```js
var objeto = document.getElementsByClassName("objeto");

for (contador = 0; contador < objeto.length; contador++) {
    objeto[contador].style.color = white;
}

function boton() {
    //esta funcion está asociada a los botones y aqui quiero conseguir la posicion de el botón que yo clique
}
```

```html
<div onclick="boton()" class="objeto">
    0
</div>
<div onclick="boton()" class="objeto">
    1
</div>
<div onclick="boton()" class="objeto">
    2
</div>
<div onclick="boton()" class="objeto">
    3
</div>
```

Comment: Deberías formular mejor tu pregunta y poner qué código has hecho hasta ahora para facilitar la respuesta.

Comment: ¿podrías también formular porqué quieres conseguir eso? No parece ser código demasiado limpio ni para nada legible, hablas de botones y son `divs`, más que añades un `onclick` a elementos que no debería tenerlo... Si explicaras el porqué de esto, sería más fácil ayudarte. Gracias.

Comment: Quiero conseguir su posición para hacer que porejemplo cuando clicques ese div o boton desaparezca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guiándome por lo que comentaste en los comentarios, el objetivo final es hacer desaparecer el elemento en el que se hizo click. Si es así, es totalmente innecesario obtener su posición, puedes hacerlo directamente haciendo referencia al propio elemento.

```js
function desaparecer(boton) {
  boton.classList.add('oculto');
}
```

```css
.oculto {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="desaparecer(this)">Button1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="desaparecer(this)">Button2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="desaparecer(this)">Button3</button>
```

También, como puedes ver, es innecesario recorrer dinámicamente los elementos para darles un estilo, con que trabajes con las clases CSS queda mucho más claro, legible y bien escrito.

Si lo que quieres es alternar entre qué elemento está oculto, haría falta un poco más de lógica.

```js
function desaparecer(boton) {
  const botonOculto = document.getElementsByClassName('oculto')[0];
  if(!!botonOculto) {
    botonOculto.classList.remove('oculto');
  }
  boton.classList.add('oculto');
}
```

```css
.oculto {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="desaparecer(this)">Button1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="desaparecer(this)">Button2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="desaparecer(this)">Button3</button>
```

Cómo sólo puede haber un elemento que tenga la clase `oculto`, obtenemos siempre el primero, por eso accedemos al primer elemento del `array` de elementos que podrían tener la clase `oculto`.

Si el elemento no existe, no "desocultamos" nada, si no daría error.

Si el elemento existe, lo hacemos y luego ocultamos el recién clicado.

Comment: muchas gracias, pero también me gustaría saber como hacer lo que decía de conseguir su posición.

Comment: mi objetivo es hacer algo como los cuadros de aqui https://robertsspaceindustries.com/roadmap/board/1-Star-Citizen